# python plotly: box plot using column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, boxplot

I am enjoying using plotly and wanted to plot boxplots for my data.

From their website, I do the following:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np

y0 = np.random.randn(50)
y1 = np.random.randn(50)+1

trace0 = go.Box(
    y=y0,
    name = 'Sample A',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(214, 12, 140)',
    )
)
trace1 = go.Box(
    y=y1,
    name = 'Sample B',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(0, 128, 128)',
    )
)
data = [trace0, trace1]
py.iplot(data)
```

The challenge that I have is that I do not know the total number of "trace" is unknown. For example:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv")
```

I would like to plot a boxplot, by column 'embarked', a boxplot of the 'fare' column. Since the total number of unique values in 'embarked' is unknown, I do not want to hardcode that in.

Does anyone know how I can do this properly in plotly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over your unique values in `embarked` and add a trace for each one. In this case there is also `nan` which needs separate treatment.

```
for embarked in titanic.embarked.unique():
```

[image]

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

titanic = pd.read_csv("http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv")

traces = list()
for embarked in titanic.embarked.unique():
    if str(embarked) == 'nan':
       traces.append(plotly.graph_objs.Box(y=titanic[pd.isnull(titanic.embarked)].fare,
                                            name = str(embarked)
                                            )
                     )
    else:
        traces.append(plotly.graph_objs.Box(y=titanic[titanic.embarked == embarked].fare,
                                            name = embarked
                                            )
                     )
plotly.offline.iplot(traces)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not seeing anything being displayed as it comes back blank.  FYI I am in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Weird. I was also using a Jupyter Notebook and just tried it with a fresh notebook.

Comment: Why do the offline thing? I read the documentation, but it really only focuses on what happens and it why it's better. Does it take up less ram?

Comment: I think on the client side it does not matter, I just usually don't need to upload my plots or share them, that's why I use offline.

Comment: OK got it so it doesn't load anything online and I don't have to deal with the privacy settings.